# How to get the first values of .txt file

Tags: python

Shown below is a .txt file and I would like to know how to extract the first three values and save them into an array. [8;8;27]. Thanks!

```
8, 8, 27, pa1-debug-a-calbody.txt

0.00,     0.00,     0.00
0.00,     0.00,   150.00
0.00,   150.00,     0.00
0.00,   150.00,   150.00
150.00,     0.00,     0.00
150.00,     0.00,   150.00
150.00,   150.00,     0.00
150.00,   150.00,   150.00
0.00,     0.00,     0.00
0.00,     0.00,   250.00
0.00,   250.00,     0.00
...
```

Comment: Open the file, read the first line, split the line on commas, take the first three values from the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,

```
f = open("input.txt","r").readline() # Read the first line from file
result=f.split(',')[:3]              # extract the first three values
result = list(map(int, result))      # Convert list to Array of int
print (result)
```

[**Output**]

**`[8, 8, 27]`**

Comment: it works! thank you